# Multi-label text classification with non-uniform distribution of class labels for every train data

Tags: python, classification, sentiment-analysis, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I have a multi-label classification problem, I want to classify texts with six labels, each text can have one to six labels but this label distribution is not equal. For example, 10 people annotated sentence1 as below:

[image]

These labels are the number of votes for that class. I can  normalize them like sad 0.7, anger 0.2, fear 0.1, happy 0.0,...
What is the best classifier for this problem?  What is the best type for labels I mean I should normalize them or not?
What keywords should I search for this kind of multi-label classification problem where the probability of labels is not equal?

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, to clarify if I understand your problem correctly. You have sentences=[sent1, sent2, ... sentn] and you want to classify them into these six labels labels=[l1,l2,...,l6]. Your data isn't the labels themselves, but the probability of having that label in the text. You also mentioned the six labels comes from human annotation (I don't know what you mean by 10 people commented, I'll guess it is annotation)

If this is the case, you can deal with the problem with multi-label classification or a multi-target regression perspectives. I'll approach what you can do with your data both cases:

1. **Multilabel Classification**: In this case, you need to define the classes for each sentence so that you can train your model. Right now you have only the probabilities. You can do that by creating a threshold and the probabilities of labels that are above the threshold can be considered the labels for a sentence. You can read more about the evaluation metrics [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification).
2. **Multi-target Regression**: In this case, you don't need to define the classes, you just use the training input and we use the data to predict the probabilities for each label. I think it is a better and easier problem, given your data collection. If you want to know more about the problem of multi-target regression, you can read more about it [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/regression-models-with-multiple-target-variables-8baa75aacd), but the models they used in this tutorial are not the the state-of-the-art (be aware of it).

**Training Models:** You can use both shallow and deep models for this task.  You need a model that can receive a sentence as input and predict six labels or six probabilities. I suggest you take a look into this [example](https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-multi-label-text-classification-with-keras/), it can be a very good starting point for your work. The author provides a tutorial on how to build a multi-label text classifier using deep neural networks. He basically built a LSTM and a Feed-forward layer in the end to classify the labels. If you decide to use regression instead of classification, you can just drop the activation in the end.

The best results are likely to be obtained by deep neural networks, so the article I sent you can work very well. I also suggest you take a look in the state-of-the-art methods for text classification, such as BERT or XLNET. I implemented a Multi-label classification method using [BERT](https://github.com/ThiagoSousa/BERT-Multiclass), maybe it can be helpful to you.